# Excel VBA - Chart Formatting axis labels

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to add axes labels to my chart. Below is a part of my code.

First, my code is not producing an error when it runs the line which adds the primary axis title. Despite not registering an error, my chart still lacks a text box for an axis title.

Second, I am not sure why my code is generating an error when I try to add the secondary axis title. I copied this section of code from the macro recorder, so I am fairly certain that the syntax is correct.

Thanks for all your help!

```
Dim myChart As Chart, cht As ChartObject
Dim rngChart As Range, destSht As String
Dim rngData As Range

destSht = ActiveSheet.Name
Set myChart = Charts.Add
Set myChart = myChart.Location(where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=destSht)

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange
Set rngData = Union(.Columns(2), .Columns(9), .Columns(10), .Columns(11), .Columns(12))
End With

With myChart
.SetSourceData Source:=rngData, PlotBy:=xlColumns
.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
.ChartStyle = 209
.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "AHT"
.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    .ChartTitle.Text = "AHT/Transfer Metrics"

'*****PROBLEM SECTION*****
.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
'*****Below is the line of code that is giving me an error*****
.SetElement (msoElementSecondaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
'******              *****

With .FullSeriesCollection(2)
    .Name = "Target AHT"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .AxisGroup = 1
    .Select
        With Selection.Format.Line
            .Weight = 1
        End With
End With
With .FullSeriesCollection(3)
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .AxisGroup = 2
    .Name = "Transfers"
    .Select
        With Selection.Format.Line
            .Weight = 1.75
        End With
End With
With .FullSeriesCollection(4)
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .AxisGroup = 2
    .Name = "Target Transfers"
    .Select
        With Selection.Format.Line
            .Weight = 1
        End With
End With
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you have not created the secondary axis yet. Try putting those 2 lines after you format all of your series

Comment: That did solve my second stated problem. However, It is still not populating a primary axis title box. I'm not getting an error for this, it seem to just be ignoring my code.

Answer (score 2):

```
    With .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .HasTitle = True
        .AxisTitle.Text = "AHT (s)"
    End With
```